# How would you draw a pie chart view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, geometry

I am currently working on a project where I need to draw a pie chart. Rather than using a third-party library I am trying to draw it with core graphics. Here is the code for drawing the pie chart.

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 + r/8, y: self.frame.height/2 + r/8), radius: r, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2 * Double(percent1 / 100)), clockwise: true)
let circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 + r/8, y: self.frame.height/2 + r/8), radius: r, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2 * Double(percent1 / 100)), endAngle: CGFloat(0), clockwise: true)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer2.path = circlePath2.cgPath
//change the fill color
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
//you can change the stroke color
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
//you can change the line width
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
```

However, this doesn't produce the desired effect since it draws the circle linearly rather than around the center.

[image]

Comment: by using one of those [awesome-ios-chart](https://github.com/ameizi/awesome-ios-chart)

Comment: Drop the `+ r/8` from both center coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your path is the arc and it closes it by connecting the end points.  You want the path to go to the center of your circle.

Add the center point to each of your paths and close them:

```
circlePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2 + r/8, y: view.frame.height/2 + r/8))
circlePath.close()

circlePath2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2 + r/8, y: view.frame.height/2 + r/8))
circlePath2.close()
```

Closing the paths will add the lines from the center point of the circle to the starting points of the arcs.  This ensures that the complete pie piece is stroked.

Comment: `circlePath.addLine(to: view.center)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, for whatever reason, the OP's center is offset by `(r/8, r/8)` from the center of the view.  OP should assign center to a variable instead of repeating it.

Comment: It was just a suggestion for the OP. You should also add the `circlePath.close()` to close the pie path

Comment: Thank you, adding the line to the center solved the problem.